# Entry Versions not showing up

Tags: entry-versions

I just noticed that none of my recent changes in an entry don't show up in the entry-versions button in the CP.

Is it possible that these entry versions are triggered by the task runner? Because I lately disabled it `'runTasksAutomatically' => false,` ?

I added a second locale to the entries and since then, the versions don't show up anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Entry versions aren't managed by tasks.

My guess is you've got "Enable versioning for entries in this section?" unchecked for that section's settings in the control panel.